# Though router-outlet is written as a tag name, still how come its a directive?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, router-outlet

I know that there are two types of Directive in angular, Attribute Directive and Structural Directive which I think both should be written along side a tag as an attribute.
Whereas a component is mostly written as directly a tag name with its selector:-
Eg:-

```
<my-app></my-app>
```

But, how is router-outlet a directive when it is written as :-

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Please correct me if what i have mentioned is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

In angular the primary difference between a Directive and a Component is that a Directive is a Component without an associated view.

So in your case the router outlet directive is notated that way so that the directive can pass through router contents to the section of the page on which it has been placed. Presumably this will be a component, of which will have a view that will be displayed int he place of the router outlet.

Comment: so, do you mean the actual directive is  wrapped around the component?
Also, what type of directive is router-outlet?